# How to authenticate a GitHub App using octokit?

Tags: node.js, github, github-api

I trying to authenticate a GitHub App to query data from a GitHub Organization. I want to get the repos, branches and some file from those branches. This is what I have so far:

```js
import { App } from 'octokit'

const app = new App({
  appId: 1234,
  clientSecret: 'abc',
  privateKey: `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  ...
  -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`,
  installationId: 1234
})

const main = async () => {
  app.octokit
    .request('GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/branches', {
      owner: 'Owner',
      repo: 'Repo',
      headers: {
        'X-GitHub-Api-Version': '2022-11-28'
      },
      installationId: 1234
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.message)
    })
}

main()
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
[@octokit/auth-app] installationId option is required for installation authentication.
```

Answer (score 1):

When an user installs the Github app you will get their *installationId*. Use this to generate an IAT.

I have used the below snippet with my ***installationId*** and able to perform the API calls

```
const app = new App({ appId: <App_Id>, privateKey: <Private_Key>, });
const octokit = await app.getInstallationOctokit(<Installation_Id>);
const resp = await octokit.request("GET /repos/{owner}/{repo}/branches", {
  owner: 'Owner',
  repo: 'Repo'
})
console.log(resp)
```

Hope this helps!